# How to understand: "the collection of objects directly referenced by an immutable object cannot change"?

Tags: python, immutability

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> An object of an immutable sequence type cannot change once it is
>   created. (If the object contains references to other objects, these
>   other objects may be mutable and may be changed; however, the
>   collection of objects directly referenced by an immutable object
>   cannot change.)

While the first part of the original quote is understandable, I don't quite get the last sentence. How can I understand the phrase: "directly referenced by an immutable object"?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to explain this will be an example.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = (a, a)
```

`b` is a tuple -- an immutable sequence. However, the objects it contains are lists, which are mutable.

It's possible to modify the mutable objects in the collection:

```
>>> a.append(4)
>>> b
([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

However, it isn't possible to change which objects exist in `a`, because it's immutable. The first and second elements of `a` will always refer to the same list, and there's no way to change that.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this example, but I still don't catch a phrase: "directly referenced by an immutable object". Isn't a in this example directly referenced by b?

Comment: @ig-melnyk The writing is a bit confusing. They mean that the _collection_ of objects -- that is, which objects are included, and where -- cannot be modified. The objects themselves can be modified if their type allows for it.

Comment: Oh, thanks. It was really confusing. Can we say that this just the same as "Identities of the immutable object always remain the same"?

Answer (score 1):

It means that an immutable `tuple` can reference a mutable object, e.g. a `list`, which can be changed, while the tuple itself is unchanged.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
my_tuple = ('a', my_list)

print(my_tuple)
>>> ('a', [1, 2, 3])

my_list.append(4)

print(my_tuple)
>>> ('a', [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand this example, but I still don't catch a phrase: "directly referenced by an immutable object". Isn't a in this example directly referenced by b?

Comment: Reading the following blog post by Luciano Ramalho, author of "Fluent Python", will help: https://standupdev.com/wiki/doku.php?id=python_tuples_are_immutable_but_may_change.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting post, though I think I understood the first part of the paragraph. It's more about the meaning of one phrase I have problem with